# How to get a character from a html to a servlet

Tags: html, servlets, getparameter

```
<form action="registerServlet">
   <tr>
        <td>Gender:</td>
        <td><select name="gender" id="gender" required>
            <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value="M">Male</option>
            <option value="F">Female</option>
            </select></td>
    </tr>   
</form>
```

This is the html code in which I have to select the gender of a registering person
Now in the `registerServlet` I want get the gender by using `getparameter()`
code for that is

```
private char gender;
gender=request.getParameter("gender");
```

But this is giving an error in eclipse. Can anyone help me how to get a character from the html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.getParameter()` returns String. You need to do this:

```
private String param;
param=request.getParameter("gender");

private char gender;
gender=param.charAt(0);
```

OR

```
private char gender;
gender=request.getParameter("gender").charAt(0);
```

Handle null checks if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of char use String,

***private String gender;
gender=request.getParameter("gender")***;

and use method="post"

Comment: Now I am using String only. Is there any way to get the character

Comment: gender.charAt(0) returns character.